# Why does a DC circuit create a constant magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

It is said that in a DC circuit $\nabla\times E =0$ because the magnetic field is not time-varying. $\nabla\times E =0$ then follows from Faradays law. But how do we know that the magnetic field is not time-varying?

Answer (score 2):

We know it because that's what we see in experiments. We summarize the results of these experiments with the [Biot-Savart law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law), which yields the magnetic field due to a static current.

Comment: Thank you, but I just realised that this creates another question for me: If we have a DC circuit with a couple of resistors, how do we know that the current through each resistor is constant? To show this I would use the results about resistors in parallell and series, but these results rely on the fact that the voltagedrop over each resistor in parallell is the same, but this result relies on $\nabla \times E=0$
which is what we are trying to show? So in order to prove that $\nabla \times E=0$, I have to use a result that relies on the fact that $\nabla \times E=0$. Do you see a solution?

Comment: @user394334 Those resistor results ultimately rely on experiments, as does $\nabla\times E =0$. You can show that they are mathematically related, but to *prove* that they model reality you have to do experiments. So, I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to understand why $\nabla \times E=0$. This could be explained by Faradays law if we can show that the magnetic field is constant, I see now that the magnetic field is constant by Biot-Savarts law if the current is constant. So I am trying to understand why the current is constant. I guess you could show that the current is constant by using Ohms law over each resistor, but then you have to show that the potential difference over each resistor is constant, which I don't know how to do.

Comment: What are the initial experiments you have to do to get the chain started?

Comment: Ultimately the end goal is understanding why resistors in parallell have the same voltage drop.

Comment: @user394334 The usual excuse is Kirchoff's voltage law. But where did that come from? Well, it came from experiments with resistors! Resistors in parallel have the same voltage drop because that's how nature works. The associated math has the form it has because resistors in parallel have the same voltage drop (and many other reasons). If you want to understand resistors, get some and experiment.

Comment: @user394334 There really aren't "initial experiments". There are networks of related experiments. Physics is not like math, where you start from axioms. Nature doesn't give us axioms, it gives us phenomena.

Comment: If you want to find out why current in a  circuit is constant in time, look up the drude model on conductivity. This is a model that is used to derive ohms law, the basic premise is this, the battery creates an electric field, charges accelerate in response, they collide with the atoms in the metal  slowing them down. This is modelled as a resistive force, similar to the terminal velocity of a sky diver, when the resistive force balances out the electric force, there is zero net force and thus the electrons can be thought of as having a constant velocity, and thus a constant current.

Comment: This is obviously an idealisation, since no individual electron has a constant velocity  however the collective 'drift' velocity is constant, and any models analysing this current to be anything other than a constant are pointless, meaning we can assume the field of a dc circuit is conservative

Comment: @jensenpaull But the "why" flows the other way. The Drude model was inspired by Ohm's law, which was inspired by experiments. To say that it explains the experiments is to engage in circular reasoning. If the experimental results had been different, we'd have a different model.

Comment: My thinking is probably because i study theoretical physics, but every result  in physics could be boiled down to "because an experiment shows this". I dissagree that it is circular, we use experiments to find out what is actually going on, and then assert that the reason why something happens is due to that 'something'. Experiments find out the nature of our universe, and this nature is the primary "why"

Comment: @jensenpaull Galileo's experiments remain fundamental to our understanding of gravity, yet the theory keeps changing. Galileo's explanation was a universal downward acceleration. Newton's was a universal force. Now, we use a geometric explanation. The experimental results are the foundation, while the "explanations" are shifty.

Answer (score 1):

My initial reaction would have been to answer like John Doty.

A second angle to look at it is time-translation symmetry. The fields ($E$ and $B$) are caused by the charge and current distributions, and if these are time-translation invariant the same must apply to the fields.

Comment: Why should we believe in time translation symmetry?

Comment: Yeah, why should we? We don't have to. The time-translation symmetry of the sources is given by the experimental setup/is an observational fact. And through basic invariance principles/symmetry arguments follows the time-translation symmetry of the fields. (And yes, if you have to, you can attribute the existence of those principles to observation...)

Answer (score 1):

A way to verify that the magnetic field is not time varying is to align the wire (or resistor) with the line North-South, and place a compass over it. A constant deflection of the needle means a constant magnetic field by definition.

Answer (score 0):

It's not that we know it. In general magnetic field is not constant in time.

It's that an important class of systems can be analyzed when we assume that electric field is conservative, and thus magnetic field is constant in time. DC circuit powered by a battery is an example of such system.

If a real system under study can't be put into agreement with DC theory, we have to loosen the assumptions. For example, when current in a circuit is driven by a rotating magnet, it is natural to relax the assumption that magnetic field is constant, and Maxwell's equations imply that electric field is no longer conservative everywhere.

Comment: But why is a DC circuit an example of such a system?

Comment: DC = dynamic current means current does not change in time. When current does not change in time, it is observed that magnetic field does not change in time. Physics is based on generalization of experiments.